# docker 1.9.0 network support in mesos

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

Is mesos provide support for docker 1.9.0 custom network creation facility?
Using docker 1.9.0 I can create my own network which binds with a custom linux bridge instead of legacy docker0 bridge, once container is launched in customed network.

```
sudo docker network create --subnet=172.23.0.0/16 bridge1
```

Create a bridged network bridge1. but previous docker version has only three networks (bridge,host,none).

So, does latest versions of marathon and mesos support this changes?

Thanking in advance.

Comment: That might conflict with https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/80c123ec50e986dc10e222401e195ce57e8f24f9/docs/networking-for-mesos-managed-containers.md

Comment: how it will conflict? if we are not using third party modules.

Comment: I meant: if mesos proposes its own implementation of networking, I don't know if it supports in parallel the docker libnetwork model.

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, Mesos does not support networks created via the `docker network create` command. For single-host networks, there is a ticket tracking the addition of this functionality [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-4354).

The community has not reached consensus on whether or not Mesos will attempt to integrate Docker's multi-host networking feature; you can find a discussion on this subject in [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-3828).